# Umbraco 7.6.0 - Site becomes unresponsive for several minutes every day

Tags: azure, umbraco, umbraco7

We've been having a problem for several months where the site becomes completely unresponsive for 5-15 minutes every day.  We have added a ton of request logging, enabled DEBUG logging, and have finally found a pattern:  Approximately 2 minutes prior to the outages (in every single log file I've looked at, going back to the beginning), the following lines appear:

> 2017-09-26 15:13:05,652 [P7940/D9/T76] DEBUG
>   Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlCacheFilePersister -
>   Timer: release.  2017-09-26 15:13:05,652 [P7940/D9/T76] DEBUG
>   Umbraco.Web.PublishedCache.XmlPublishedCache.XmlCacheFilePersister -
>   Run now (sync).

From what I gather this is the process that rebuilds the umbraco.config, correct?

We have ~40,000 nodes, so I can't imagine this would be the quickest process to complete, however the strange thing is that the CPU and Memory on the Azure Web App do not spike during these outages.  This would seem to point to the fact that the disk I/O is the bottleneck.

This raises a few questions:

1. Is there a way to schedule this task in a way that it only runs
   during off-peak hours?
2. Are there performance improvements in the newer versions (we're on 7.6.0) that might improve this functionality?
3. Are there any other suggestions to help correct this behavior?

Hosting environment:

- Azure App Service B2 (Basic)
- SQL Azure Standard (20 DTUs) - DTU usage peaks at 20%, so I don't think there's anything there.  Just noting for completeness
- Azure Storage for media storage
- Azure CDN for media requests

Thank you so much in advance.

**Update 10/4/2017**

If it helps, It appears that these particular log entries correspond with the first publish of the day.

Comment: Does republishing the cache from the Umbraco backoffice also cause the site to become unresponsive?

Comment: Well unfortunately we don't want to take the site down for an additional 15 minutes to test that.  However I do have some additional information.  The log items I referred to seem to be corresponding to the first node publish of the day (or the first in several hours).

Comment: Which version of Examine you have in your project? What value you have in umbracoContentXMLStorage and umbracoContentXMLUseLocalTemp keys in web.config? And finally - do you have fcnMode="Single" in your httpRuntime set?

Comment: Examine:  0.1.83.0.  Neither of these web.config values exist, so they would be at the default.  httpRuntime has fcnMode "Single"

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? We have a site load-balanced on Azure Cloud Service running 7.5.3 and often after a publish from the admin site the frontend sites restart half way through writing their XML cache file, which is then corrupt and has to be rebuilt from scratch, which takes about 5 minutes (around 70,000 nodes, 280MB cache file)

Comment: @germankiwi In our particular situation, we never did find a cause for the issue.  Our band-aid solution is to force a recycle every morning at 4am.  We have not had the outage occur since we implemented this restart.

Comment: @Keith cool, thanks for the reply

Comment: @Keith if it's any help, what "fixed" these issues for us (well, made them disappear) was to change the Cloud Service tier from A2 to D2_v2, which offers better disk performance. The write time of the XML cache reduced from 20-30s to 6-15s, and we haven't experienced any outages since the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

I don't feel like 40,000 nodes is too much for Umbraco, but if you want to schedule republishes, you can do this:

You can programmatically call a cache refresh using:

`ApplicationContext.Current.Services.ContentService.RePublishAll();`

[(Umbraco source)](https://github.com/umbraco/Umbraco-CMS/blob/e0025db56d52b770d2b3aedbd48a3b804fd15ef0/src/Umbraco.Core/Services/ContentService.cs#L1012)

You could create an API controller which you could call periodically by a URL. The controller would probably look something like:

```
public class CacheController : UmbracoApiController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage Republish(string pass)
    {
        if (pass != "passcode")
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, new
            {
                success = false,
                message = "Access denied."
            });
        }

        var result = Services.ContentService.RePublishAll();

        if (result)
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new
            {
                success = true,
                message = "Republished"
            });
        }

        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new
        {
            success = false,
            message = "An error occurred"
        });
    }
}
```

You could then periodically ping this URL:

`/umbraco/api/cache/republish?code=passcode`

I have a blog post on how you can read on how to schedule events like these to occur. I recommend just using the Windows Task Scheduler to ping the URL: https://harveywilliams.net/blog/better-task-scheduling-in-umbraco#windows-task-scheduler